# WPF C# Cefsharp Ver. 71, i have a URL and a cookie which will bypass login and show end results, till then show loading

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

WPF C# Cefsharp Ver. 71, i have a URL and a cookie which will bypass login and show end results.
However, till the time i get back response page loaded in my cefsharp component, the xaml remains blank and i want to show "please wait, loading..." sign. How to i do it?
I do have a code to show the same but i guess placing of that is not correct. Below is example:

```
// Called on Loaded even of xaml
private async void OnLoad() 
        {


            if (Loaded)
                return;

            try
            {
                IsBusy = true; // if true we show overlay progress bar user control

                var api = OrganizerApi.GetInstance();


                string key = await GetVtsToken();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                {
                    var cookieManager = Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager();
                    Cookie cookie = new Cookie
                    {
                        Name = api.SecurityDomain,
                        Value = key
                    };
                    cookieManager.SetCookie(api.OrganizerUrl, cookie);
                    Address = api.OrganizerUrl;
                    Loaded = true;
                }

                IsBusy = false;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                _logger.Error(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

//Overlay progress bar user control show "please wait, loading..." modal

```
<progress:OverlayBox OverlayOnElemement="{Binding ElementName=OrganizerGrid, Mode=OneWay}"
                             IsShown="{Binding Path=IsBusy}"
                             Message="{translation:Translation msg.loading.generic}"
                             Grid.Row="1"  Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
        />
```

Comment: Version 71 is old and unsupported, there are many security vulnerabilities,  you should upgrade ASAP. The IsLoading property can be bound to, will be true while page is loading,  false when finished

Comment: @amaitland, ok, thanks for the response. Can you help me in the guide or steps page lins which would help me or my team to upgrade v71 to latest stable version easily? I remember that in my team we tried to simply upgrade it with latest available stable version but solution did not build at all, so we had to undo all of those things. However, simple new minimal example did work well. So, may be we missed something which we are not able to find out. thanks in advance.

Comment: The release notes on GitHub contain details on the changes made between each version.  See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases the biggest set of changes is likely https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2743 review the release notes for additional details. If you upgraded more frequently you'd find it much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to latest version as latest version has support for this type of features